# iTerm2 open file

Tags: bash, vagrant, iterm2

iTerm2 has a nice ⌘-click to open a file in your IDE.

The problem is I'm running a web server via Vagrant, so `/home/vagrant` isn't really a physical directory that iTerm2 can access.

Is there a way I can either:

A.) Map /home/vagrant/ to /Sites in my .bash_profile

B.) Run it through a Find/Replace script that returns the modified path?

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: How would it open something not mounted on your computer? Do you want it to launch a web page or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not way to configure it using .bash_profile... but there is a solution inside your iTerm2's preference.

Preferences -> Profiles -> Semantic History. Change to **Run command...** and fill with:

```
sh ~/click-handler.sh \1 /home/vagrant /Sites
```

create ~/click-handler.sh:

```
old_filepath=$1
old_basepath=$2
new_basepath=$3
new_filepath="${old_filepath/$old_basepath/$new_basepath}"
open $new_filepath
```

Let's try!

Comment: Thanks! I tested and your script works when I execute the shell locally in the terminal:


`sh ~/click-handler.sh /home/vagrant/fis.dev/craft/app/consolecommands/BaseCommand.php /home/vagrant /Sites`


However, nothing happens when I click it within iTerm2.

Comment: Could you fill Run Command with: echo 'sh ~/click-handler.sh \1 /tmp /tmp/site' > /tmp/log - and put the result of /tmp/log here?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Udlei. You definitely pointed me in the right direction. The problem with "Run Command" is that iTerm2 (currently 3.0.15) doesn't respond to clicks if it doesn't recognize the directory in the filesystem. I changed it to "Always Run Command" and was able to use your code to come up with this. I really appreciate your help.

```
#!/bin/bash

# iTerm2 > Profiles > Adv -> Semantic History > Always Run Command:
# sh ~/click-handler.sh \1 /home/vagrant /Sites \5

original_filepath=$1
vagrant_basepath=$2
local_basepath=$3
current_pwd=$4

# remove quotes from var_dump if present
original_filepath_temp="${original_filepath%\"}"
original_filepath="${original_filepath_temp#\"}"

# look for /home/vagrant in the $original_filepath
if [[ $original_filepath =~ ^(\/home\/vagrant) ]];
    then
    new_filepath="${original_filepath/$vagrant_basepath/$local_basepath}"
    # echo $new_filepath > ~/Library/Logs/iterm.log
    /usr/local/bin/subl $new_filepath
# default local handling
    else
    original_filepath="$current_pwd/$original_filepath"
    # echo $original_filepath > ~/Library/Logs/iterm.log
    /usr/local/bin/subl $original_filepath
fi
```